# Sync Exchange Contacts Subfolders with Android

Tags: contacts, sync, exchange

Finally I managed to sync Exchange Server with Galaxy S3 and had managed to make it all work fine except the annoying contacts thing...
The android sync only contacts that are in the main contacts folder won't sync contacts sub folders.
Email Subfolders from some reason does sync.
Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been [reported](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8045) and seems like it might be solved with some [release](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8045#c48)

In the mean while, an [alternative](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8045#c26) would be:

> - label contacts rather than put them in folder

Answer (score 0):

Try the android "Smart Contacts" app and create groups. These can then be accessed when sending emails using std android app.